# JPA Detected reentrant flush

Tags: spring, jpa, flush, openjpa

I have little problem with openjpa implementation of jpa with spring 2.5. My dao method:

```
@Transactional
public User getUserByName(final String name) {
    return (User) getEntityManager().createQuery("select u from User as u where u.name = :name").setParameter("name", name).getSingleResult();
}
```

returns org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException:

```
org.apache.openjpa.persistence.InvalidStateException: Detected reentrant flush.  Make sure your flush-time instance callback methods or event listeners do not invoke any operations that require the in-progress flush to complete.
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.flushSafe(BrokerImpl.java:1904)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.flush(BrokerImpl.java:1679)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.isInMemory(QueryImpl.java:956)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:838)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:779)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingQuery.execute(DelegatingQuery.java:525)
at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:254)
at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:317)
at org.jpa.dao.UserDao.getUserByName(UserDao.java:71)
```

//EDIT
EntityManager settings:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.OpenJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="false"/>
        </bean>
    </property>

    <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
        <bean class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver"/>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaDialect">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.OpenJpaDialect"/>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
```

How do you obtain an EntityManage? In dao class:

```
@PersistenceContext(type = PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
protected EntityManager entityManager;
```

What is wrong? Any idea?

Comment: Can't see any Spring-related items in the stacktrace. How do you obtain an `EntityManager`?

Comment: Set up readOnly attribute equal to true and see what happens.

Comment: I've just added information about EntityManager. I've set up @Transactional(readOnly=true), is there another way to set readOnly??

Comment: Just an advice: you can NOT call a readOnly=true method in a readOnly=false method. I think it explains why you get your exception.

Comment: I removed (readOnly=true) attribute, exception still appears.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, and modify my entity for the primary key:

```
@Id
//@Basic(optional = false)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
```

maybe can help you.